# Open cart page is not loading

Tags: php, opencart

I am making a website in opencart. I made a catagory mobile. when I add 5 subcatagory under it, it works fine and page load perfectly.

but as soon as I add another catagory it shows nothing on page load.

it is happning for all catagory means opencart is not allowing me to add more than 5 subcatagory.

I am using opencart 1.5.4

Comment: http://multimerch.com/blog/blank-pages-in-opencart-most-common-causes/
this link will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Open cart's index.php, Add the following line,

```
ini_set('display_errors','1')
```

It will print the error and file location. Have fun :)

Comment: Make sure u delete this hack, once you move to production server. Or else, it will expose all your file path. :)